# Share factory view model between fragment and activity in JAVA

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I have this

```
class ForceUpdateViewModelFactory(
    private val mApplication: Application,
    private val mForceType: ForceUpdateType
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        require(modelClass == ForceUpdateViewModel::class.java) {
            "Unsupported model class: $modelClass"
        }
        return ForceUpdateViewModel(mApplication, mForceType) as T
    }
}
```

and I use it in a `Fragment`.

```
    class ForceUpdateViewModel(
    application: Application,
    forceType: ForceUpdateType
) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val mUpdatePickataleEvent = LiveEvent<Void>()
    private val mMaybeLaterEvent = LiveEvent<Void>()

    val maybeLaterBtnVisibility: LiveData<Int> = getApplication<App>().configManager
        .effectiveConfigurationSingle
        .map { config ->
            if (forceType == ForceUpdateType.HARD) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        }.toObservable().asLiveData()

    fun getUpdatePickataleEvent(): LiveData<Void> = mUpdatePickataleEvent

    fun getMaybeLaterEvent(): LiveData<Void> = mMaybeLaterEvent

    fun onUpdatePickataleBtnClick() {
        mUpdatePickataleEvent.raise()
    }

    fun onMaybeLaterBtnClick() {
        mMaybeLaterEvent.raise()
    }

}
```

The problem is that I would like to listen for the `getMaybeLaterEvent` in the parent Activity, but that Activity **is in Java**. I have no idea how to share the view model with the Activity in this case.
Normally, *I THINK*, I'd do it by using `val sharedViewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()` or something of the sorts, but i have no idea how to do that in Java.

Comment: Do you mean you have control of the source code of the Activity, but you don't want to convert it Kotlin, and just want to know how to do the equivalent of `by activityViewModels()` in Java?

Comment: I guess that could help, yeah. If using `by activityViewModels()` is the way to share a factory view model in kotlin ... if not, then i need another solution :)

Comment: Side note in case you're new to using Kotlin. It's unconventional to use getter functions. See here for the pattern typically used when you want to expose an instance of something publicly with a narrower type: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#names-for-backing-properties

Answer (score 0):

When you use `by activityViewModels()` in a Fragment, that's equivalent to using `by viewModels()` in an Activity. It's a ViewModel scoped to the associated Activity lifecycle either way.

Since you want a ViewModel reference in your Activity and you want to keep it Java, you can't use a property delegate. This would be the equivalent of `by viewModels { ForceUpdateViewModelFactory() }` in the Activity:

```java
private ForceUpdateViewModelFactory viewModel;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //...

    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ForceUpdateViewModelFactory())
        .get(ForceUpdateViewModel.class);

    //...
}
```